# Django-rest-framework serializer makes a lot of queries

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have this model:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    ....
    owner = ForeignKey(CustomUserModel)
    ....
```

And I have this DRF serializer that returns a list of `Place`s (the view calling it uses DRF's `generics.ListAPIView` class):

```
class PlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserModelSerializer() # Gets only specific fields for a place owner

    class Meta:
        model = Place
```

The problem is, when the serializer gets a query that returns, let's say... 50 places, I can see (in `connection.queries`) that a query is being made for each `owner` foreign key relation, which sums up to a lot of queries. This of course has a big impact on performance.

Also important to mention is that for the view calling the serializer I had `get_queryset()` return only `Place`s that are in a certain distance from a center point using a custom query. I used Django's `extra()` method for that.

I have tried using `select_related` and `prefetch_related` with the query mentioned above, but it doesn't seem to make any difference in terms of queries being made later on by the serializer.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

[select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) will work as expected with serializers.

Make sure you're setting that in the 'queryset' attribute on the view if you're using the generic views.

Using select_related inside 'get_queryset' will work too.

Otherwise the only thing I can suggest is trying to narrow the issue down with some more debugging. If you still believe there's an issue and have a minimal example that'll replicate it then raise the issue as a ticket, or take the discussion to the mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Tom. Can I use the 'queryset' attribute if the query needs to get values from the request? For now I'm using `get_queryset()` for that reason.

Comment: @TomChristie Hi can you help me here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744664/django-tweak-the-rest-framework-serializer-to-getting-a-different-json-structure