# Django tweak the rest framework serializer to getting a different json structure

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django app using rest framework in which i am serializing a model in my serializers.py as follows:

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
    model = Course
    depth = 1
```

and the output i am getting on my api is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "course_id": 992, 
    }, 
    {
        "course_id": 994, 
    }
]
```

But now i would like to tweak the json structure a bit and i want to get an output as follows:

```
[
    {
        "course": {
            "course_id": 992, 
        }
    }, 
    {
        "course": {
            "course_id": 994, 
        }
    }
]
```

Here is my api.py:

```
class CourseSubjectList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        subs = Course.objects.all()
        serialized_subs = CourseSerializer(subs, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_subs.data)
```

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably have to implement a wrapper for your `CourseSerializer`. Try the code below.

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
    model = Course
    depth = 1


class CourseWrapperSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    course = CourseSerializer(read_only=True, source='*')
```

The crucial thing here is `source='*` indicating that the entire object should be passed through to the field. Then in your view use the wrapper instead of the original serializer.

```
class CourseSubjectList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        subs = Course.objects.all()
        serialized_subs = CourseWrapperSerializer(subs, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_subs.data)
```

Comment: hi.thanks for replying. I tried your method but it didnt change anything in the output

Comment: Post also your view that uses the given serializer.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Didn't know about the `source='*'` option.